# Same-name classes defined in different files of a program

Tags: c++, class

C++ Primer says that if we want to use a class in several files, the class definition must be the same in each file.
I tried writing a program with two source files as:
a.cpp:

```
class C {int a;};  int main(){return 0;}
```

b.cpp:

```
class C {int b;};
```

then compiled the program and it gave me no error.

So, does that mean that what the book says is classes in different files are different classes even if they have the same name?

EDIT:
I am still new and don't know what linking object files is.
I use Eclipse IDE, I created a C++ project with the two files in it.
I tried defining a variable in both files with the same name to see if the files are linked and it gave me an error: multiple definitions of the same variable.

Comment: Did you *link* both *object* files?

Comment: Can you show how you compiled and built the program?

Comment: Those two classes **are** the same. The different member names don’t matter; it’s the types that have to be the same. Even if they weren’t, that would be a violation of the ODR (one definition rule), which does not require a diagnostic.

Comment: Why class C is having different attributes names 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: I think what C++ Primer meant is that you can _forward_ declare a class in one file just to make its definition visible to that file and implement it somewhere else. So you would have, say `class C;` as a forward declaration in `a.cpp` and `class C { ... }` in `b.cpp` or something like that.